# How to get the hundreds place value from an integer value?

Tags: java, if-statement, int

Given an `int` in Java, I want to be able to determine the digit in the hundreds place of the number. For example:

- an input of 124 should give an output of 1
- an input of 357 should give an output of 3,
- an input of 653 should give an output of 6.

I have tried the code below, but am getting the following error:

> The operator / is undefined for the argument type(s) boolean, int

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Random;
class adam{
  public static void main(String[]args)
  {
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int first =   rnd.nextInt(900)+100;
    int second =  rnd.nextInt(900)+100;
    int third =  rnd.nextInt(900)+100;

    System.out.println(first);
    System.out.println(second);
    System.out.println(third);

    if ((first==second&&first==third)/100);
    System.out.println(first);
    System.out.println(second);
    System.out.println(third);
  }            
}
```

### Question

- How can I get the digit in the hundreds place value from a Java `int`?
- Why am I getting this error in my code?

Comment: No idea what you are asking, but your if statement consist of `boolean/100` which does not work.

Comment: int ans = 124/100 will give you 1

Comment: What is this line supposed to be doing? `if ((first==second&&first==third)/100);`

Comment: Remember that what you put in the `if`'s parentheses is only the *condition*, and then, following the `if`, usually in curly brackets, the command(s) that actually has to run if the condition is true.

Comment: You certainly don’t want that semicolon after the `if (…)`. Probably curly braces instead, as @RealSkeptic suggested.

Comment: I moved your problem description to the top of the post and clarified your expected inputs and outputs. It's usually easier to understand a question with the context before the code. I also updated your title to more accurately reflect your question. Please try to ask questions as clearly as possible. The [ask] page has some great tips for doing this. Good luck!

Comment: Hello! I further edited your question for clarity so that people know exactly what you're asking and can hopefully get you a useful answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me guess, you probably want something along these lines:

```
if (first / 100 == second / 100 && first / 100 == third / 100) {
    System.out.println(first / 100);
    System.out.println(second / 100);
    System.out.println(third / 100);
}
```

This will print the same value three times if the condition is true, though, which may not be exactly what you want. For example, if the numbers are 756, 723 and 792, it will print 7 three times. Anyway, you can try it out, see if you can modify it to your needs, and if not, explain where I guessed wrong.

Edit: to reduce the number of divisions you can alternatively just divide all the values by 100 before the `if` statement:

```
first /= 100; // or if you prefer: first = first / 100;
second /= 100;
third /= 100;
if (first == second && first == third) {
    System.out.println(first);
    System.out.println(second);
    System.out.println(third);
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was trying to do , Thanks! I just got all confused with the stuff inside of if (...)

Answer (score 1):

> How can I get the digit in the hundreds place value from a Java `int`?

You're on the right track with your integer division. You've also got the modulo operator at your disposal for handling numbers >= 1000.

Easiest to just show the math, this should be enough for you to go on:

```
2468                       (1) start with an integer, 2468
2468 / 100 = 24            (2) divide by 100 to discard 10's and 1's
             24 % 10 = 4   (3) modulo 10 to discard 1000's and higher
                       4   (4) and your left with your 100's digit
```

As you can see, you could stop at (2) if you know you won't see numbers >= 1000. As an aside, you'd want to take the absolute value first if you have to deal with negative numbers.

> Why am I getting this error in my code?

Because this statement is nonsense:

```
if ((first==second&&first==third)/100);
```

In particular the condition is:

```
(first==second&&first==third)/100
```

And if you split it into its parts you can see what is happening:

```
first == second              (1) == produces a boolean
first == third               (2) == produces a boolean
(1) && (2)                   (3) && produces a boolean
100                          (4) 100 is an int
(3) / (4)                    (5) now you have boolean / int
```

And you can't divide a `boolean` by an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is the third last digit in the number.
So you can try this:

```
String temp = number + "";
System.out.println(temp.charAt(temp.length() - 3));
```

Comment: The OP can best tell. It’s my impression you are answering a different question, namely how many times the number 100 appears among the three random numbers. My interpretation was that the OP was after the digit in the 100s place, e.g., 6 if the number was 690.

Comment: Please include an explanation in your answer, not just code: [answer]

Comment: Sure I just added an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

1. **How can I get the digit in the hundreds place value from a Java int?**

**This code is working:**

```
import java.util.Random;
 class Adam{
  public static void main(String[]args)
  {
Random rnd = new Random();
int first =   rnd.nextInt(900)+100;
int second =  rnd.nextInt(900)+100;
int third =  rnd.nextInt(900)+100;

System.out.println(first);
System.out.println(second);
System.out.println(third);
 int first1=first/100;
int second1=second/100;
 int third1=third/100;
   System.out.println("an input of "+first +"  an output of "+first1 +" first");
System.out.println("an input of "+second +" an output of "+second1+" first");
System.out.println("an input of "+third +" an output of "+third1+" first");
   }            
}
```

2. **Why am I getting this error in my code?**
        --->The boolen can't devided by an int